# Advanced form library for Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap

There is a Twitter Bootstrap form library that I am not able to find, but I viewed it before.

It allowed detailed markup and tooltip type functionality for drop downs.

All the data in the drop downs were country names. So if this rings a bell, please let me know the name of the library!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you are looking for is Chosen? Give a look at [harvesthq page on github](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it was Select2:

> Select2 is a jQuery based replacement for select boxes. It supports
>   searching, remote data sets, and infinite scrolling of results. Look
>   and feel of Select2 is based on the excellent Chosen library.

http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/